# How do I make find fail if -exec fails?

Tags: bash

When I run this command in the shell (in a non-empty directory):

```
find . -exec invalid_command_here {} \;
```

I get this:

```
find: invalid_command_here: No such file or directory
find: invalid_command_here: No such file or directory
find: invalid_command_here: No such file or directory
```

(and so on for each file)

I need `find` to fail after the first error. Is there any way to get this to work? I can't use `xargs`, as I have spaces in my path, but I need the script calling this to return an error code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871147/how-to-exit-from-find-exec-if-it-fails-on-one-of-the-files

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a limitation of `find`. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) specifies that the return status of `find` is 0 unless an error occurred while traversing the directories; the return status of executed commands doesn't enter into it.

You can make commands write their status to a file or to a descriptor:

```
find_status_file=$(mktemp findstatus)
: >"$find_status_file"
find … -exec sh -c 'trap "echo \$?" EXIT; invalid_command "$0"' {} \;
if [ -s "$find_status_file" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "An error occurred"
fi
rm -f "$find_status_file"
```

Another method, [as you discovered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49042/how-do-i-make-find-fail-if-exec-fails/49047#49047), is to use xargs. The `xargs` commands always processes all files, but returns the status 1 if any of the commands returns a nonzero status.

```
find … -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 invalid_command
```

Yet another method is to eschew `find` and use recursive globbing in the shell instead: `**/` means any depth of subdirectories. This requires version 4 or above of bash; macOS is stuck at version 3.x so you'd have to install it from a port collection. Use `set -e` to halt the script on the first command returning a nonzero status.

```
shopt -s globstar
set -e
for x in **/*.xml; do invalid_command "$x"; done
```

Beware that in bash 4.0 through 4.2, this works but traverses symbolic links to directories, which is usually not desirable.

If you use zsh instead of bash, recursive globbing works out of the box with no gotchas. Zsh is available by default on OSX/macOS. In zsh, you can just write

```
set -e
for x in **/*.xml; do invalid_command "$x"; done
```

Comment: The `xargs` approach works in general but somehow breaks on `bash -c` commands. For example: `find . -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I '{}' bash -c "foo {}"`. This is executed multiple times whereas `find . -name '2*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I '{}' foo {}` is executed once and fails. Any idea why?

Comment: @DKroot Never use `{}` inside `bash -c`. This takes the file name and inserts it directly inside the shell command. If the file name contains characters which have a special meaning in the shell such as spaces, the shell interprets these special characters as such. If you need a shell, pass `{}` as a separate argument, e.g. `bash -c 'foo "$0"' {}` (note the double quotes around `$0`, as well).

Comment: OK, quoting questions aside, why does the following not stop on the first error??
`find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I '{}' bash -c 'foo "$0"' {}`

Comment: @DKroot Why would it stop on an error? xargs always runs the command on all the items.

Comment: I'm trying to use this answer: the xargs (`find . -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 invalid_command`) approach. This stops on the first error correctly: `find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I '{}' foo {}`. Great! But the same approach doesn’t work with `bash -c` (above). The only difference between the two is `bash -c`.

Comment: @DKroot `xargs invalid_command` is a special case: xargs can't even run the command, and so it stops trying. If xargs can run the command and the command returns a failure status, it moves on to the next item normally. This is the correct, documented behavior! I don't know why you expect otherwise.

Comment: @Giles Because by `invalid_command` I meant a script or a command returning a non-zero exit code. I think @Steven Fisher meant that too. Good point on RTFM. I went to xargs docs and converged onto a solution for custom scripts. Returning exit code 255 would tell `xargs` to terminate early with `bash -c` or without. All is good! Thanks.

Comment: @Gilles Isn't ``... | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'echo "$0"' {}`` the same as ``... | xargs -0 -n 1 bash -c 'echo "$0"'``?

Comment: @Rolf Yes, if you're passing `-0` and `-n 1` then I don't think `-I {}` makes any difference.

Answer (score 26):

I can use this instead:

```
find . -name *.xml -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 invalid_command
```

Answer (score 24):

`xargs` is one option. However, it's actually trivially easy to do this with `find` as well by using `+` instead of `\;`

```
-exec  utility_name  [argument ...]   {} +
```

From the [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html):

> If the primary expression is punctuated by a plus sign, the primary shall always evaluate as true, and the pathnames for which the primary is evaluated shall be aggregated into sets. The utility utility_name shall be invoked once for each set of aggregated pathnames. Each invocation shall begin after the last pathname in the set is aggregated, and shall be completed before the find utility exits and before the first pathname in the next set (if any) is aggregated for this primary, but it is otherwise unspecified whether the invocation occurs before, during, or after the evaluations of other primaries. **If any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, the find utility shall return a non-zero exit status.** An argument containing only the two characters “{}” shall be replaced by the set of aggregated pathnames, with each pathname passed as a separate argument to the invoked utility in the same order that it was aggregated. The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system’s {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded. If more than one argument containing only the two characters “{}” is present, the behavior is unspecified.

Comment: this works for me, shouldn't this be the correct answer?

Comment: @Higgs On stackoverflow, 90% of the time being first is all that matters.

Comment: @Higgs and @Swiss — This will work for some use cases, but it requires the `-exec`ed command to accept multiple arguments (in this case all the elements found by the `find` expression), since this is what the `+` operator does. It collects node names, then executes `-exec` with all those names as arguments. Which, if I'm not mistaken, could exceed the max number of arguments possible in the shell, for one, and again also needs support from the invoked script or program.

Comment: For what it's worth, this did not work for me with the current zsh. As for being first, it does matter more than it should… but six years later is a hard sell. 